# Нужна ли запятая в конструкции "к тому же(,) если"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*К тому же(,) если в 2011-2014 годах белорусы платили пошлину за экспорт нефтепродуктов в российский бюджет, то с 2015 года оставляют ее себе.* Нужна ли запятая перед "если" в данном предложении?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*К тому же если в 2011-2014 годах белорусы платили пошлину за экспорт нефтепродуктов в российский бюджет, то с 2015 года оставляют ее себе.*

"К тому же" и "если" - два отдельных союза, можно заменить: " но если". При встрече сочинительного и подчинительного  союзов запятая между ними **не ставится**, если в главном предложении есть вторая часть подчинительного  союза, здесь она есть: если.., **то**. В этом случае придаточное нельзя изъять из предложения, "то" мешает.

Answer (score 3):

Не нужна ни в этом предложении и ни в каком ином.

*К тому же если*  - составной союз в начале предложения: не расчленяется.

Но Грамота.ру допускает, что запятая может быть авторской, при каком-то особом логическом ударении.

***[СОСТАВНЫЕ СОЮЗЫ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3)***

Кстати, в перечень составных союзов *к тому же если* не попадает (нельзя же объять необъятное).